# What charger for a 13s10p Li-ion battery pack?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger

I plan to make a battery pack for my vehicle, 13s10p Li-ion battery. It gives me 30Ah.

If one battery can be charged at 1A, can I charge 10 batteries in parallel at 10A?

For now I have a 2A charger and the calculations come out to me that I will be charging the entire package for 15 hours and I would like it to charge as fast as possible - of course within safety limits.

---

Update:

Here are the specifications of the Samsung INR18650-30Q cell I want to use:

Nominal discharge capacity: 3000mAh

Charge: 1.50A, 4.20V,CCCV 150mA cut-off

Discharge: 0.2C, 2.5V discharge cut-off

Nominal Voltage: 3.6V

Standard Charge: CCCV, 1.50A, 4.20 ± 0.05 V, 150mA cut-off

Rapid Charge: CCCV, 4A, 4.20 ± 0.05 V, 100mA cut-off

Charging time: Standard charge : 180min / 150mA cut-off / Rapid charge: 70min (at 25℃) / 100mA cut-of

Max. continuous discharge (Continuous): 15A(at 25℃), 60% at 250 cycle

Discharge cut-off voltage: 2.5V

Cell weight: 48.0g max

Cell dimension: Height : 64.85 ± 0.15mm / Diameter : 18.33 ± 0.07mm

Operating temperature (surface temperature): Charge : 0 to 50℃

Storage Temperature: 1.5 year -30~25℃(1*) / 3 months -30~45℃(1*) / 1 month -30~60℃(1*)

And datasheet:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rVakjo344K7ZV_1GL6SCfT8tnT-cgtVM/view

Comment: You have ten in parallel but, what if one is slightly more discharged than the others? How can you guarantee that all 10 amps are not flowing into one battery (worst case)?

Comment: what if i use bms it works same with charge and discharge, i want to know max amp possible to charge my battery pack.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your batteries manufacturers charge specifications.

They will tell you the charger specifics. Some batteries charge faster and heavier than others.

Also some chargers are constant voltage others are constant current some are pulse or taper up or taper down.

These charge rates are very important to keep from damaging the batteries themselves. In some instances it might simply harm the batteries' capabilities in others you risk fire and or explosion.

I have seen those results first hand. Even just the loss of the batteries can be financially devastating let alone fire or worse!

I know my answer is probably not the technical one that you had hoped for but because of the serious issues involved here PLEASE adhere to the battery manufacturers charge specs!

Comment: Standard charge CCCV, 1.50A, 4.20 ± 0.05 V, 150mA cut-off. and if i have 10 batteries in parallel can i use 15A charger?